# Transaction from ADO.Net in Snapshot Isolation Level in SQL Server 2008 R2 not changing to default isolation level after commit/rollback

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, ado.net, snapshot

I have the following code in C# using ADO.NET for updating data in a SQL Server 2008 R2 database using the SNAPSHOT isolation level. This code is working perfectly. However, if I go to another page in my ASP.Net app after this, where a query runs between this database table joined with another database table on same server, then I get an error that says:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Snapshot isolation transaction
>   failed accessing database 'Member_Security' because snapshot isolation is
>   not allowed in this database. Use ALTER DATABASE to allow snapshot
>   isolation.

Query that throws an error as pasted above, if it runs after the SNAPSHOT transaction code:

```
select 
   e.EmpId, e.EmpHours, m.SecurityLevel, m.IsPriveleged 
from 
   Emp e 
inner join 
   Member_Security.dbo.Members m
```

If I do not run the transaction in code below in SNAPSHOT level, then there is no problem.

Why is this happening and how can I correct it?

I think in this case SNAPSHOT isolation level is not getting reset to what was before this code ran.

Code that runs perfectly:

```
con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EMP"].ConnectionString;
con.Open();
tran = con.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Snapshot);  
cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0; 
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.Text = "Update emp set empcomm = 200 where empage > 40;"
cmd.Transaction = tran;

try {
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    tran.Commit();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    try 
    { 
        if(tran != null) 
           tran.rollback();
    } 
    catch{}
}
finally 
{ 
     DAL.ResetTransactionIsolationLevel(); 
} //NEED THIS TO SOLVE THIS PROBLEM
```

**UPDATE 1:**

It seems there is a problem when using an isolation level other than the default one from ADO.Net code according to this paragraph taken from following url: [Need to explicitly set Isolation Level when using non-default isolation level in ADO.Net code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ha4240h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> After a transaction is committed or rolled back, the isolation level of the transaction persists for all subsequent commands that are in autocommit mode (the SQL Server default). This can produce unexpected results, such as an isolation level of REPEATABLE READ persisting and locking other users out of a row. To reset the isolation level to the default (READ COMMITTED), execute the Transact-SQL SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED statement, or call SqlConnection.BeginTransaction followed immediately by SqlTransaction.Commit. For more information on SQL Server isolation levels, see "Isolation Levels in the Database Engine" in SQL Server Books Online.

**UPDATE 2:**

The only way I avoided this was to set isolation level to Read Committed after the above transaction was done i.e. call the method 'ResetTransactionIsolationLevel' in the finally block of above transaction. If I did this then I did not see any problems when executing cross-database queries after the SNAPSHOT isolation level. I added the finally block to show this solution in above code snippet.

```
 public static void ResetTransactionIsolationLevel()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EMP"].ConnectionString);


        try
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "set transaction isolation level read committed";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

From here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb(v=vs.110).aspx
Snapshot isolation must be enabled by setting the ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON database option before it is used in transactions.

Run this on your database:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase
SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON
```

**UPDATE** If you want to Read Committed **SNAPSHOT** in subsequent transactions without specifying it implicitly, also run:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase
SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON
```

Note that this is NOT read committed, and all data is still going through tempdb, so you really need to consider the capacity for your db and application.

Comment: That will not solve my problem. I want the database I am using to have READ COMMITED automatically restored after the SNAPSHOT transaction runs. This should happen automatically.

Comment: @Sunil i really want to know where you got the 'This should happen automatically' information?

Comment: Its in the docs for SQL Server. Transaction level being used in a session last for the connection session. So if in a stored procedure you have set isolation level as SERIALIZABLE, then once the procedure completes, the isolation level should return to the isolation level that was in effect before the procedure started.

Comment: The doc at this url: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx says: "If you issue SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL in a stored procedure or trigger, when the object returns control the isolation level is reset to the level in effect when the object was invoked. For example, if you set REPEATABLE READ in a batch, and the batch then calls a stored procedure that sets the isolation level to SERIALIZABLE, the isolation level setting reverts to REPEATABLE READ when the stored procedure returns control to the batch"

Comment: @Sunil From your very own link: The ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION database option must be set to ON before you can start a transaction that uses the SNAPSHOT isolation level. If a transaction using the SNAPSHOT isolation level accesses data in multiple databases, ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION must be set to ON in each database.

Comment: If you look at my C# code I am setting the isolation level to SNAPSHOT. "tran = con.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Snapshot);" I am then updating data in only first database and all this works perfectly. So transaction happens successfully. Its only after this that I query across 2 databases, but in normal Isolation Level i.e. I do not specify SNAPSHOT when running the query across 2 databases.

Comment: @Sunil as the MSDN link you posted clearly states, you have to set the db (or both) to ALLOW for that code to work.
Also, your code has an empty catch block which explains why you are not seeing exceptions.